# Go boltDB query using bolthold 3 conditions

Tags: go, boltdb

So I had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058075/go-boltdb-query-using-bolthold) before and I had an answer below the question which worked, but I just realized that the query I came out with does not work as planned.

Basically now if it works like this

```
(if the roleskey contains any of the roles in slice) and (if the tenantID is an empty string) or (if tenantIDKey is equal to tenantID)
```

But what I need is

```
(if the roleskey contains any of the roles in slice) AND (if the tenantID is an empty string OR if tenantIDKey is equal to tenantID)
```

Here is my current query:

```
query := bolthold.Where(roleskey).ContainsAny(bolthold.Slice(roles)...).And(tenantIDKey).Eq("").Or(bolthold.Where(tenantIDKey).Eq(tenantID))
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```golang
query := bolthold.
         Where(tenantIDKey).Eq("").
         Or(
           bolthold.
           Where(tenantIDKey).
           Eq(tenantID)
         ).
         And(roleskey).
         ContainsAny(bolthold.Slice(roles)...)
```

Or

```golang
query := bolthold.
         Where(tenantIDKey).ContainsAny("", tenantID).
         And(roleskey).
         ContainsAny(bolthold.Slice(roles)...)
```

Or

```golang
query := bolthold.
         Where(tenantIDKey).In("", tenantID).
         And(roleskey).
         ContainsAny(bolthold.Slice(roles)...)
```

Comment: but this looks like the same query just reversed.

Comment: @Marius yes it just reversed please test it once it may also reverse the query generate internally.